# Received images are sometimes resized (smaller) on Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook-messenger, amio

Some images sent by users on Facebook Messenger and received through Amio webhook are smaller than original one. Is there any way how to get the full size image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amio.io doesn't manipulate any media which go through the platform. It is stored and forwarded as it is. The image shrinking is actually done on the Facebook Messenger iOS/Android app when sending by user. [Facebook recently released](https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2017/11/making-visual-messaging-even-better-introducing-high-resolution-photos-in-messenger/) new version of Messenger app which allows 4K resolution. It is available in selected countries however.